# Fill Missing Data Timeseries in Python

Tags: python, date, time-series, imputation

I have 2 Weeks data from 2022-06-23 to 2022-07-06 within format like this:

| date | hour | datetime | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-23 | 0 | 2022-06-23 0:00 | random1 | xx | abc | 12 |
| 2022-06-23 | 0 | 2022-06-23 0:00 | random1 | xx | cwe | 10 |
| 2022-06-23 | 0 | 2022-06-23 0:00 | random2 | yy | mmm | 1231 |
| 2022-06-23 | 1 | 2022-06-23 1:00 | random1 | xx | abc | 12 |
| 2022-06-23 | 1 | 2022-06-23 1:00 | random0 | aa | cwe | 50 |
| 2022-06-23 | 2 | 2022-06-23 2:00 | random1 | xx | abc | 12 |
| 2022-06-23 | 2 | 2022-06-23 2:00 | random1 | aa | abc | 1 |
| 2022-06-23 | 2 | 2022-06-23 2:00 | random1 | yy | lcg | 112 |
| 2022-06-23 | 2 | 2022-06-23 2:00 | random1 | xx | vbn | 12 |
| 2022-06-23 | 2 | 2022-06-23 2:00 | random1 | xx | dgb | 12 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-07-06 | 23 | 2022-07-06 23:00 | random1 | xx | vbn | 100 |
| 2022-07-06 | 23 | 2022-07-06 23:00 | random1 | xx | lcg | 22 |
| 2022-07-06 | 23 | 2022-07-06 23:00 | random1 | yy | dgb | 4561 |
| 2022-07-06 | 23 | 2022-07-06 23:00 | random1 | aa | vbn | 3 |

Hour for 0 to 23 every date.
Let say i have missing value like this on 2022-07-06 at 11:

| date | hour | datetime | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-06 | 10 | 2022-07-06 10:00 | random1 | xx | vbn | 10 |
| 2022-07-06 | 10 | 2022-07-06 10:00 | random1 | xx | lcg | 220 |
| 2022-07-06 | 10 | 2022-07-06 10:00 | random15 | yy | dgb | 451 |
| 2022-07-06 | 12 | 2022-07-06 12:00 | random1 | aa | vbn | 30 |
| 2022-07-06 | 12 | 2022-07-06 12:00 | random1 | xx | vbn | 10 |
| 2022-07-06 | 12 | 2022-07-06 12:00 | random1 | xx | lcg | 22 |
| 2022-07-06 | 13 | 2022-07-06 13:00 | random5 | yy | dgb | 4561 |
| 2022-07-06 | 13 | 2022-07-06 13:00 | random1 | aa | vbn | 3 |

Any suggestion how I can solve the missing value and missing hour?

Any sugesstion and help will be much appreciated

Comment: Hi, can you specify what you want to achieve? So far it really is not clear what your problem is and how it could be solved.

Comment: @ffrosch The problem  there is missing value on my data. I want fill those missing value for specific missing hour

Comment: Ok, so I assume your data is in a pandas dataframe and you want to impute the data based on the other data?

Please edit your question and add this information as well as a small sample of code/data that can be copied and used to provide a solution for you :-)